redirect to login page fails if token refresh fails using Keycloak.js
I'm encountering an issue with Keycloak in my React application. When the token is no longer valid and a refresh is not possible, a proper logout or redirect to the login page fails. If the logout function is used and the token can't be refreshed, the following window is displayed:

It seems that Keycloak requires a valid token to perform a proper logout. Therefore, I tried calling the login function to directly go to the login page, but this does not work as expected. The useEffect hook runs indefinitely. (it seems only with proper logout the cookies saved in the browser gets removed)
Expected Behavior:

Redirect to the login page if the token refresh fails

Based on the browser logs, the behavior is indeed correct:
App.tsx:67 
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token 400 (Bad Request)
not authenticated
ERROR
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/

Attempts:

Tried combinations of the following:

keycloak.clearToken() --> keycloak.login() using / not using checkLoginIframe: true
Placing the logout or login functions in the error fields
Adding window.location.reload() to force a re-render



Considered:

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/12114
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/12002#issuecomment-1128896662
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/12183

Keycloak Settings:
Default Keycloak used from https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker with the following settings:

Code:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

function bootstrap() {
  let realm = 'dev';
  const clientId = 'test';
  const hostname = window.location.hostname;

  if (hostname !== 'localhost') {
    realm = 'dev';
  } else {
    realm = hostname;
  }

  const kc = new Keycloak({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    realm: 'dev',
    clientId: 'test',
  });

  return { keycloak: kc, realm, clientId };
}

const App = () => {
  const [keycloak, setKeycloak] = useState({});
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { keycloak } = bootstrap();

    keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: true }).then((authenticated) => {
      setKeycloak(keycloak);
      setAuthenticated(authenticated);
    });

    keycloak.onAuthRefreshError = () => {
      console.log('ERROR');
      keycloak.clearToken();
      keycloak.logout();
    };

    keycloak.onAuthLogout = () => {
      console.log('not authenticated');
      keycloak.login();
    };

    keycloak.onTokenExpired = () => {
      keycloak.updateToken(10).then((refreshed) => {
        if (refreshed) {
          console.info('Token refreshed: ' + refreshed);
        } else {
          console.info('Token not refreshed, valid for ' + ' seconds');
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        console.error('Failed to refresh token');
      });
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    keycloak && authenticated && (
      <div>hello world</div>
    )
  );
};

export default App;

Dependencies:
{
  "name": "keycloak-test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^24.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}


What if you call keycloak.init again (instead of keycloak.login())?

Why not just call the logout method with a redirectUri parameter (see the API)?
